# How to avoid react rerendering whole tree on simple className changes?

Tags: javascript, svg, reactjs

I have some nested React components, the inner of which is a large `svg` graph with hundreds if not thousands `line` and `rect` elements. To enable some application-wide behaviour and appearance changes I thought to change the `className` of the uppermost component. The problem is, that the whole application re-renders if I do that.

I understand that this behaviour is somewhat intended, in the sense of a unidirectional render flow, but I thought React would be smarter about what it can reuse and keep DOM changes to a minimum.

Minimal example here: https://jsbin.com/rabofewawu/1/edit?html,js,output
As you can see, the line pattern in the SVG changes every time you press 'here' though I only want the background color to change.

A similar, but more extreme, example arises when I try to zoom and pan the `svg` by changing the `transform` property of an inner `g` element. Using d3, I simply change the attribute. With react, my `render` function gets called, the updated state results in an updated `transform` property, and the whole group is re-renderd from scratch instead of changing the DOM attribute.

Am I missing something? Whats the React way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take this simple harmless looking render function:

```
render(){
    return <div>{Date.now()}</div>;
}
```

In React's mental model this would always display the current number every millisecond. **React conceptually updates infinite times per second**. The inputs of render here are everything in the world, but we happen to just use the clock. Given the same world, we get the same output from render and thus it's idempotent.

Well crap... we don't have infinitely fast computers so we need to compromise. Instead of render's input being everything we restrict it to state and props (and context).

In this restricted setting use of Math.random or Date.now breaks the rules. If you need to use the output of these, it must go through state or props first. How would this look? Well we can use a deterministic random number generator and store the seed in state. Here's a [modified version of your component](https://jsbin.com/vufive/2/edit?js,output) doing that:

```
var MyComponent = React.createClass({
  displayName:"MyComponent",

  getInitialState(){
    return {
      seed: Math.floor(Math.random()*0xffffff)
    };
  },

  render: function() {
    // make a random number generator with the given seed
    var rng = new Chance(this.state.seed);
    function random(x){
      return rng.floating({min: 0, max: x, fixed: 7})
    }

    var s=100, lines = [];

    for (var i=0; i<100; i++) {
      var line = { x1: random(s), y1: random(s), x2: random(s), y2: random(s) };

      lines.push(React.createElement("line", line));
    }

    return React.createElement("svg", { height: s, width: s}, lines);
  }
});
```

Rendering less than infinite times per second, and rendering only certain components is an optimization. Optimizations should not affect the behavior of the program.

If you wanted different random numbers, you could set the seed to a different random number. Using real `Math.random()` here is okay because state is the result or i/o operations in your code, and you're invoking this setState in response to some other i/o (e.g. a click handler).

---

Time is similar; if you want the current time to be rendered, use a setTimeout and setState with the current time. You can then display it how you like in render, including passing it down to other components and doing any kind of math on it you like.

Comment: I think I chose a bad example, using the Time, I only wanted to emphasize that the component is indeed being rendered anew. Which of course it is, as it returns a different DOM tree. Nevertheless your hint got me thinking and the real issue was: the `svg` element had not EXACTLY the same markup (6th or 7th number after decimal point) which was the true reason for the re-renders.

Comment: My point was that rerendering shouldn't cause any issues. If it is, you have very fragile components.

Answer (score 2):

You can control this with the component's `shouldComponentUpdate` function. By default this always returns true (so the component will always re-render).

There's a little bit of documentation for this function here https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-shouldcomponentupdate